# avoid firing of update in EF when there's no change in object property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

using CurrentValues.SetValues(object) it always update the record even if there's no change in object property value. I say that it update the row by looking the LastUpdated field on my table. Is there a way to avoid firing of update in EF if there no change in object property value. Right now what i did is i create a reflection to determined if there's dirty object and return to true, from that i will know if i need to fire the update. here's my implementation

```
            var person = _context.Persons.Find(personInfo.Id);
            if (ObjectHelper.IsDirtyObject(person, personInfo))
            {
                _context.Entry(person).CurrentValues.SetValues(personInfo);
            }
```